# Select linked cell, cell next to checkbox, or get the checkbox name

Tags: vba, checkbox

I have a document full of Checkboxes and I dont want to write specific VBA code for each checkbox because the file size needs to stay relatively small. What I am trying to do with my code is when the checkbox is checked, it automatically selects the cells next to it(not hard coded in using "Range") and then perform the rest of the programed VBA function.

How do I either get the name of the checkbox, select the linked cell, or select the cell next to the checkbox using some kind of "offset" property? I am completely stumped!

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please check this post: Loop through checkbox controls in vba. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987593/loop-through-checkbox-controls-in-vba-userform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Form Controls` instead of `ActiveX Controls` for Check Box.

[image: Select ActiveX]

Following code will not be work with check box from ActiveX Controls. Also, you need to assign macro to the checkbox, simply trying to run this code from VBEditor will give error.

[image: Add Macro]

Assuming all the checkboxes are on same sheet, select all your checkboxes and assign them same macro, something like this

```
       Sub checkBoxHandler()

            Dim shp As Shape

            Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
            MsgBox shp.Name 'Name
            MsgBox shp.TopLeftCell.Offset(1).Address ' 1 Rows below checkbox
            ActiveSheet.Range(shp.ControlFormat.LinkedCell).Select ' Select linked cell.

            Set shp = Nothing
        End Sub
```

here Application.Caller helps VBA to identify which checkbox is being clicked.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I entered the code, and used the debugger and it popped up a type mismatch error 13 for the first line after the Dims. How can I fix this?

Comment: Putting it simply, I just want this to happen: When a checkbox is clicked. I want it to immediately select the linked cell. I feel like your code you posted is so close to what I want it to do. This portion of code is a little above my expertise. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I have tried to explain the process by adding images and some more explanation. Please have a re-look at the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got it to do what I was hoping it would do by using your code. I am new to VBA, I appreciate your expertise!