# How to Loop Through ActiveX Checkboxes on VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, checkbox, activex

I'm actually trying to make a userform that controls every checkbox in the Workbook Sheets (it's mostly graphs that shows the data from a specific period for the Company), since every graph has the same checkboxes (ActiveX ones) with the same names on them I though about making a Userform that is always active and in this way the client can just select which ones he will use and it would just loop through the other sheets without a problem.

But here is the problem first of all my code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.OLEObjects("chkAno1").Object.Value = 1
    Next ws

ElseIf Me.CheckBox1.Value = False Then
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.OLEObjects("chkAno1").Object.Value = 0
    Next ws

End If
```

I did it with only one checkbox to test it out (There is a "chkAno1" in every sheet that I want to affect) but everytime I run the code and click the checkbox I get " Error 1004: The Method "OLEObjects" from object "_Worksheet" Failed", and what's weird is that If I change "ws" with "ActiveSheet" the code works fine, but only updates the currently open sheet.

So I'm at a loss right now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop Through CheckBox Controls in VBA UserForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987593/loop-through-checkbox-controls-in-vba-userform)

Comment: When changed to activesheet  , did you test every sheet in turn? Are there any hidden sheets ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help. I found out the problem, there was some sheets without any Checkboxes on them, so the Code kept giving me the error.

The solution I found for it was to put `On Error Resume Next` at the beggining and it worked like a charm! (I actually needed to put it on the graphs as well)

But in the end I ended up reworking the code to affect directly the Graph using `ws.ChartObjects("grafico").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).IsFiltered = True` instead of `ws.OLEObjects("chkAno1").Object.Value = 1` Because at the end the process of updating every checkbox and after that all the charts would be actually really slow on some older computers and updating directly the Graph showed a great increase in speed.

Thanks to everyone that Commented and I hope the solution I found can help someone else!